# Как сделать выбор города Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать функционал выбор города. Например: При входа на сайт, выходит модальное окно, с select, и там в option будет два города Москва и Питер, при выборе одного option, на верхний части сайта в header.php сохраняется город. Тогда же должны поменяться адреса и товары соответствующему городу, и при заказе метка с городом, чтобы менеджера понимали с какого города.

Что можете посоветовать? Есть ли какие то ссылки на похожие задачи, или мануал. С чего начать.

Желательно все это было в одном домене, и не в одном инфоблоке, чтобы памяти много не занимало.

Я думал может лучше создать свойства СПИСОК и значение Москва с чекбоксом, при установленном свойстве выводился товар. 
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Для реализации функционала выбора города можно использовать следующий подход:

1. Создать свойство "Город" для профиля пользователя. Оно может быть типа "Список" с вариантами ответов "Москва" и "Питер", и соответствующими значениями для каждого города.
2. Создать компонент модального окна, который будет выводить список городов в формате select с возможностью выбора города. При выборе города в select отправляется AJAX-запрос на бэкенд, который сохраняет выбранный город в профиле пользователя.
3. В верхнем меню (например, в header.php) вывести выбранный город из профиля пользователя или значение по умолчанию, если город еще не выбран.
4. Для каждого товара и адреса создать свойство "Город" и указать для каждого значения г